# when saving a screenshot with Watir the png is empty or 0kb

Tags: ruby, cucumber, screenshot, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using cucumber and watir-webdriver and am trying to take a screenshot on failure.
With the examples I found, it is technically working but the png files that are created are blank or 0kb in size.

I have tried chrome and firefox and am using a win7 x64 system.

I am putting the following in my env.rb file.

```
After do |scenario|
 if scenario.failed?
  #Dir::mkdir('screenshots') if not File.directory?('screenshots')
  screenshot = "./screenshots/FAILED_#{scenario.name.gsub(' ','_').gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-     z_]/, '')}.png"
   @browser.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot)
   embed screenshot, 'image/png'
 end
end
```

How can I get it to actually capture what is on the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try saving the screen shot with this:

```
browser.screenshot.save 'screenshot.png'
```

More information: http://watirwebdriver.com/screenshots/

Comment: I was having exactly the same problem and this fixed it for me with Firefox, but I still have the issue with Chrome. I've tried outputting a base-64 encoded image and it behaves the same (works with FF and blank with Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by updating my chromedriver binary file. To debug this I have used: 
`browser.screenshot.save('your_file'.png)` 
in the step, where I got this error: 
`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension`